# Is putIfAbsent method blocking or not?

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` in my application, but not quite sure how to deal with it. Looking at the sources I didn't find any `synchronized` statement of `Lock` acquisition.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) is also not quite clear. All it says is that the operation performs atomically.

So, is `public K putIfAbsent(K, V)` non-blocking?

Comment: I guess your question should be answered with another question: do you need to synchronize a critical section composed by a single atomic operation?

Answer (score 3):

#### A note on the `java.util.concurrent.Concurrent*` API

Unfortunately, the Javadocs of the `java.util.concurrent.Concurrent*` types aren't all as specific about how to achieve concurrency guarantees as that of [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and high expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional specification as java.util.Hashtable, and includes versions of methods corresponding to each method of Hashtable. However, even though all operations are thread-safe, ***retrieval operations do not entail locking***, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access. This class is fully interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety ***but not on its synchronization details***.

Essentially, it has shown over the years that the early [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) implementation that was very agressive in terms of locking doesn't scale for very large and very widely used and shared maps. As with databases that distinguish between read and write locks, something more efficient was needed.

#### Your specific method

Your specific method is "non blocking" as it doesn't use monitors to guarantee consistency and atomicity. It relies on the JVM's memory model guarantees for `volatile` references, which you encounter throughout the implementation. What's specifically interesting in these implementations is that you can see loops like these (in the private `doPut()` method):

```
outer: for (;;) {
    for (Node<K,V> b = findPredecessor(key, cmp), n = b.next;;) {
        ...
        break; // restart if lost race to replace value
```

So, competing threads are operating on the same objects at the same time without blocking, but they might take several attempts at succeeding. In other words, rather than blocking, CPU is "burned".

Comment: Huh, I knew it, I knew it)). But the fact that "retrieval operation does not entail locking" doesn't imply that neither does putIfAbsent. Is it safe to assume that `putIfAbsent` of `ConcurrentHashMap` and `ConcurrentSkipListMap` is non-blocking? As far as I know, `ConcurrentHashMap` uses (or used to use)) lock-stripping.

Comment: The current `ConcurrentSkipListMap.putIfAbsent()`  implementation is non-blocking, unlike that of `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent()`, which is blocking. However, I don't see any guarantee in the contract about things staying this way.

Answer (score 1):

`public K putIfAbsent(K, V)` is non-blocking.
`ConcurrentSkipListMap` uses CAS. Compare-and-swap (CAS) is an atomic instruction.